# gRPC stuck on onCompleted call

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have a producer-consumer server-side stream structure where the producer and consumer are running in two different threads. I understand that streamObserver is not thread-safe so I have the consumer calling onNext to stream back results while the producer waiting for the completion of the consumer then call onCompleted or onError to finish the call. Below are some simplified code:

`producer-consumer.java`

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<?> future = service.submit(() -> consumer(responseObserver));
future.get(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
responseObserver.onCompleted();
```

consumer method in `producer-consumer.java`

```
private void consumer(ServerCallStreamObserver<?> responseObserver) {
  ...
  while(someCondition) {
     ...
     responseObserver.onNext(item);
  }
}
```

This code works fine but if I move the onCompleted call inside the consumer then I'll always get timeout error waiting for the completion of the consumer to finish

modified consumer method

```
private void consumer(ServerCallStreamObserver<?> responseObserver) {
  ...
  while(someCondition) {
     ...
     responseObserver.onNext(item)
  }
  System.out.println("before onCompleted"); // this line will print
  responseObserver.onCompleted(); // application stuck here until parent thread wait time out
  System.out.println("after onCompleted"); // after a while this line will print
  System.out.println(responseObserver.isCancelled()); // true
}
```

Comment: This seems likely to be the result of a bug somewhere else.  Do you have a custom interceptor?

Comment: @LarrySafran no we don't use interceptor but just a client response observer with onNext, onError and onCompleted method.

Comment: Maybe grabbing a stacktrace while it is stuck will help clarify what is happening.